# Why Node.js not recognizing image path

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to get my images to load up using node the relative path; however it keeps giving me a 404 error (not found). Here is my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.render("home");
});


app.get("/fallinlovewith/:thing", function(req, res){
  var thing = req.params.thing; 
  res.render("love", {thingVar: thing});
});


app.get("/posts", function(req, res) {
    var posts = [
        {title: "Post 1", author: "Susy" },
        {title: "My adorable pet Bunny!", author: "Bob" },
        {title: "Can you belive this pomsky?", author: "Ethan" },
      ];

  res.render("posts", {posts: posts});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
console.log("server started");
});
```

Here is my home.ejs file

```
<% include  partials/header %>
<h1>This is the home page</h1>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gp3ZKiwZMvg/hqdefault.jpg">
<img src="public/images/rsz_biopic.jpg"></img>
<% include  partials/footer %>
```

My css file, and image src http path are both working, It's just the relative path. If anyone could help out that would be awesome!

Comment: What is the full text of the error message, and what does your directory structure look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `<img src="public/images/rsz_biopic.jpg"></img>` to `<img src="images/rsz_biopic.jpg"></img>`. Basically, remove `public`.

You already name `public` the folder for static files  `app.use(express.static("public"));`. It shouldn't be used again in the path for the files.

```
<% include  partials/header %>
<h1>This is the home page</h1>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gp3ZKiwZMvg/hqdefault.jpg">
<img src="images/rsz_biopic.jpg"></img>
<% include  partials/footer %>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

Add to top of file:

```
var path = require('path'),
```

You need to define that path in node.

Change:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

To:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This way "/public" is a valid location

Comment: That's correct. But he needs to require `path` package.

Comment: I'm assuming 'path' is a package I will need to npm install before this example works?

Comment: It is built into node I believe.